# Gimp: why can't I register this?

Tags: python, blender, gimp, python-fu, gimpfu

I'm writing an add-on for Blender to sync it with Gimp and this script should be able to start from within Gimp, but I can't register it... Why?

blender_gimp_sync.py:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

#!/usr/bin/env python

from gimpfu import *

def blender_gimp_sync():
    image_dir = "/home/antoni4040/Έγγραφα/Layout.png"
    image = gimp.pdb.gimp_file_load(image_dir, image_dir)
    gimp.Display(image)


register(
    "python_fu_bgsync",
    "Blender-Gimp Sync",
    "Syncronize Gimp with Blender for texturing",
    "Antonis Karvelas",
    "Antonis Karvelas",
    "2012",
    "<Image>/Image/Blender-Gimp Sync",
    "*",
    [],
    [],
    blender_gimp_sync
)   

main()
```

It's really strange...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You didn't say which error you are getting - but since you posted your source file I think I can guess it:
GIMP expect's it's plug-ins to be exectuable by the system - and what tell's Posix (linux included) systems that a file should be executed with a particular interpreter or shell is the  shebang line - the line that goes `#!/usr/bin/env python` in your example.

This line, however, has to be the *first* line in your file - the `#!` characters in it should be the first two characters in the file. The line denoting the character encoding - `# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-` should come after it - it has to be the second line in the file, no blank lines between them).

And finally, be sure to set the script as executable, by running "chmod a+x " on the Python file.

related to it, but not being what is causing the problem, putting the menu path along with the script menu name is deprecated in GIMP - the correct way to do it is, after the "date" parameter, pass just the name that should show in the menu -- "Sync" - and pass the menu path as a named parameter, at the end of the call, like: `menu="<Image>/Image/Blender-Gimp"`

Comment: Thanks a lot!!! Sorry for no errors, but when it doesn't register it just doesn't register, it doesn't show any errors... And, on more thing: I can't use it without creating an image first, but I want to be able to do that... How?

Comment: Hi - -sorry - I forgot about it not showing the errors when registering fails. As for the not needing an image, just drop the "*" on the image type parameter, and pass an empty string instead.

Comment: Thanks, go and answer this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12732194/gimp-start-script-without-image

Comment: One more thing: I'm trying to open it using batch mode and do something like this: cmd = "\'(python_fu_bgsync RUN-NONINTERACTIVE)\'"
 subprocess.Popen(['gimp', '-b', cmd]), but, even if it says batch command executed successfully, nothing happens. Why?