# Gimp: start script without image

Tags: python, image, plugins, gimp

Well, I'm trying to write a python plug-in for Gimp, but it wont start without first loading an image... What can I do about that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I commented on your other question  [Gimp: why can't I register this?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12713399/gimp-why-cant-i-register-this/12719613#comment17177876_12719613) - the problem is that you are passing the "*" value on the "image type" parameter when you are making your register call.

Just drop it, and pass an empty string instead.